# Advantage Database, case sensitivity, and collations

Tags: sql, collation, case-sensitive, advantage-database-server

I have something similar to this in my Advantage database:-

```
drop table #test;

create table #test (x cichar(50));
insert into #test (x) values ('cheese');
insert into #test (x) values ('fromage');
insert into #test (x) values ('Queso');

select
  t1.x t1_x,
  t2.x t2_x
from
  #test t1
  inner join
  (
    select
      'CHEESE' x // String literal will be of type VARCHARFOX
    from
      system.iota
  ) t2
  on t1.x=t2.x
```

This gives me the message:-

> poQuery: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = HY000;   NativeError = 2213;
>   [iAnywhere Solutions] [Advantage SQL Engine]**Invalid comparison or
>   operation on strings with different collations.**  **  Script error
>   information:  -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 137 (line:
>   5 column: 1)

When I would like:-

```
t1_x    t2_x
cheese  CHEESE
```

This is because the 'CHEESE' string literal becomes type VARCHARFOX and the column in the temp table is of type cichar because I want case insensitive comparisons.

I can fix this instance by adding a "COLLATE ads_default_ci" to the comparison, however this is cumbersome and I can never remember the exact syntax of it.

I think I must be doing something fundamentally wrong with the column types or the configuration of the database, what's the elegant/right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much the string literal which is the problem here, string literals usually behave just fine.

They get [the COERCION_COMPATBILE collation](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/index.html?master_case_insensitive_field_type.htm):

```
TRY drop table #test; CATCH ALL END TRY;

create table #test (x cichar(50));
insert into #test (x) values ('cheese');
insert into #test (x) values ('fromage');
insert into #test (x) values ('Queso');

select
  t1.x t1_x,
  'CHEESE' t2_x
from
  #test t1
where
  t1.x='CHEESE'
```

The problem is that you are introducing a derived table and that the ADS engine determines the data type of the derived table field to be `VARCHARFOX(6)`:

```
select
  'CHEESE' x
from
  system.iota
```

I don't think that there is an easy way to do this.

I have created [an upstream request on the ADS forum](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/forum/questions/5955/why-is-the-default-character-field-type-varcharfox).

Also I have added a [feature request](http://feedback.advantagedatabase.com/forums/2671-general/suggestions/6840736-add-support-for-different-char-literals) based on this. If it was implemented the solution would be:

```
select
  CICHAR'CHEESE' x
from
  system.iota
```

I think that this is would be a clean solution.

You should also be aware of something else:

There is a collation [associated with each connection](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/WebHelp/Advantage11.1/master_collation_support.htm).

The NCHAR also built-in support for case-sensitive **and** case-insensitive collations. Which one is used depends on the collation of the current connection.

You can set the collation for the current connection using the [AdsSetCollation](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/WebHelp/Advantage11.1/ace_adssetcollation.htm) function (or it's equivalent for you development environment, for example in ARC you can set it in the connection properties).

Comment: Yes, you're right you do have to have a derived table for it. I was hunting for the right phrasing to describe it. But that you get something different from the derived table vs the literal is odd.